# Getting textarea value in nextjs

Tags: html, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, react-hook-form

I try to get data from a textarea in a react functional component, I'using  Reducer hook to fetch data from the form, i use reducer to get data from the dom I don't understand what I've done wrong help would be very appreciated.

```
import Success from "../../components/singleElements/Success"
import Error from "../../components/singleElements/Error"
import { useQueryClient, useMutation } from "react-query"
import { addOnePub, getPub } from "../../lib/helper"
import { useReducer } from "react"

export default function Insertpub(){
//I use this reducer  to fetch the data
  const formReducer = (state, event) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    };
  };
//then  get the textfield changes from here
  const [formData, setFormData] = useReducer(formReducer, {});
  
    const queryClient = useQueryClient()
    const addMutation = useMutation(addOnePub, {
        onSuccess : () => {
            queryClient.prefetchQuery('pub', getPub)
        }
    })

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
      
        e.preventDefault();
        
        if(Object.keys(formData).length == 0) return console.log("Don't have Form Data");

        let {pub} = formData;
        const model = {
            pub
        }

        addMutation.mutate(model)
        console.log("the data is correctly inserted")
    }

    if(addMutation.isLoading) return <div>Loading!</div>
    if(addMutation.isError) return <Error message={addMutation.error.message}></Error>
    if(addMutation.isSuccess) return <Success message={"Added Successfully"}></Success>
```

//When I insert a value in this text area it returns null object

```
    return (
        <form  onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <textarea
              className="bg-gray-200 w-full rounded-lg shadow border p-2"
              rows="5"
              placeholder="Ecrivez votre publication ici"
              OnChange={setFormData}
              name="pub"
              id="pub"
             
            ></textarea>

            <div className="w-full flex flex-row flex-wrap mt-3">
              
              <div className="w-2/3">
                <button
                  type="submit"
                  className="float-right bg-indigo-400 hover:bg-indigo-300 text-white p-2 rounded-lg"
                >
                  Publier
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
    )
}
```

Normally when I submit the form it should return value populated from the reducer hook but i got anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be because of the typo in the capitalization (case matters):

```
 OnChange={setFormData}
```

Should be

```
 onChange={setFormData}
```